# Сменить цвет таба в TabLayout

Tags: java, android, android-tabs, android-tablayout

Есть `TabLayout` с некоторым количеством табов, добавляемых с помощью `ViewPager`.
Каким образом выделить один таб среди остальных? К примеру, нужно чтобы 2 таб имел отличный от других цвет. Или же проще будет изменить цвет текста в этом табе? Как можно это реализовать?
Пока в голову идет только создание `customView`, что-то такое:

```
tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setCustomView(...);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте таким способом:

```
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout); 
    ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) tabLayout.getChildAt(0); 
    ViewGroup vgTab = (ViewGroup) vg.getChildAt(tabCustomNumber); 
    vgTab.setBackgroundColor(tabCustomColor);
```

Answer (score 4):

Для начала в drawable задайте селектор

tab_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_background_selected" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_background_unselected" android:state_selected="false" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" />
</selector>
```

для активной вкладки tab_background_selected.xml (атрибуты задайте как Вам необходимо)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
</shape>
```

для неактивной вкладки tab_background_unselected.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="#000000" />
</shape>
```

и в styles.xml определите

```
<style name="Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout" parent="android:Widget">
    <item name="tabBackground">@drawable/tab_background</item>
</style>
```